# In the Google Play Console, can I update an internal release? Or do I have to create a new one entirely?

Tags: android, google-play

I have a release in internal from the Google Play Console. I have made some updates and have the APK ready. Can I update the Internal release, or do I have to create a new one to check it out?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow club :)

Answer to your question is: You'll have to release a new apk with the incremented build number. but you can keep the version number same if you want.